# Cannot copy sqlite file into bundle/app, resource for iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, resources, copy, bundle

I've been writing this app for iPhone and I need to use sqlite. I have pre-loaded my sqlite with a bunch of data, I copied that sqlite file into my project folder. And when I launch the app, it seems like the sqlite data file was not copied to the simulator's app file (the document place). Here's my code:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"moviedbl.data"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success){
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"moviedbl.data"];
        //NSString *defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"moviedbl" ofType: @"data"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if(!success){
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
```

It seems that defaultDBPath refers to the app folder in the simulator, which originally does not contain any sqlite file, and instead, is actually waiting for a sqlite file to be copied to it. From what I understand, to copy the file, we should get the file from our bundle (not sure if bundle refers to our project folder or what, but I assumed it is our project folder) and copy it to our simulator. I've been stuck on this for days, please enlighten me... Thankyou very much in advance!!!

UPDATE:
So I actually got it working after all. At first I thought it was because I didn't copy the files from mainBundle or something, but it turns out that I did when I opened the actual folder of the .app in the path. I saw that the database it actually included. Something weird is that it doesn't have a file type, but in xCode it shows the file type as "data", so I kept using ofType: @"data". So in the end I changed it to ofType: @"" and it worked! Anyways! stupid me, but thanks for everyone who tried to help!! :D

Comment: Code seems fine. Db file exist in your resources and file name is correct?

Comment: Have you checked by changing the DB extension from moviedbl.data to moviedbl.sqlite or moviedbl.sqlite3.

Comment: show me what is your `dbPath` ?

Comment: my dbPath was Users/usrname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/appSerialCode... I am assuming this should be right. And I tried changing .data file to .sqlite or .sqlite3, but didn't have any luck! ummm.. so my question is that is it correct to try to copy something from that same path? because my project folder is saved elsewhere, and I don't find it logical not to go to my project folder to copy the datafile!

Comment: I got it figured out! check my update! thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"moviedbl.data"];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]==NO){

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"moviedbl" ofType: @"data"];
   BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

    if(!success){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"moviedbl" ofType: @"data"]; but it returns nil...would you know why that is?

Comment: I am pretty sure I have the data file saved in my project location too, not just a reference.